# Posting list to Json without square brackets in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to pass 10 country names at once to my payload by converting it to list. But i'm facing problems while executing the program as list comes with [square braces] that i'm unable to remove.

How can i send an entire list without square brackets to my payload. I tried json.dumps(payload) it's still not leaving the square braces.

```
format of my payload
payload= {"world" :
              {"continent": [
                              {"country": "HongKong"}
                            ],
                "planet": "earth"
              }
         }
my file-
file.csv
country
HongKong
USA
UK

how i expect the output to be-
payload= {"world" :
              {"continent": [
                              {"country": "HongKong"},{"country":"USA"}, 
                                                        {"country":"UK"}
                            ],
                "planet": "earth"
              }
         }

what i'm currently getting-
payload= {"world" :
              {"continent": [
                              {"country": ["HongKong","USA","UK"]}
                            ],
                "planet": "earth"
              }
         }
```

Comment: No json dump will ever get you what you want as its invalid JSON

Comment: Without those [ ] it’s not JSON.

Comment: i tried `','.join(repr(e) for e in mylist` and then i applied str replace to get rid of the double quotes/square braces, but again it's not getting me closer to the results.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible as that is a dictionary and it can only have one value and one key, the key in your case in Country, the value can only be one item hence why it is passed as a list. What you can do however is turn your list into a single string with the .join() method, maybe something along the lines of “, “.join(name_of_list). Your dictionary will then have the following entry:
“Country”: “Hong Kong, USA, etc.”

Comment: just corrected my output to reflect how it must actually look like. :-)

Comment: That seems like a very strange way to have a dictionary entry but sure. So looking at your desired output you have a list of dictionaries, 3 to be exact, what you need to do is a for loop through the files to create a dictionary and append it to a list. Then once you have the list you add it as an entry to your main dictionary. Hope this helps!